# Maximizing throughput of a large LOAD DATA INFILE 'xyz.txt' IGNORE query

Tags: mysql, performance, file-io

The source has 800M+ entries (docID, needleID). The resulting table whittles this number to something close to 150M unique docIDs. Takes quite a bit of time to execute the query, though. Looking at the documentation there doesn't seem to be much tweaking possible. Am I missing something?

The query looks like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'someFile.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE temp.someTable (docID,needleID)
```

[as per requested the table is :]

```
    CREATE TABLE `someTable` (
                 `docID` char(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
                 `needleID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                 PRIMARY KEY (`docID`)
                 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query runs on a MacPro 4 cores 32G RAM and currently takes 3hrs to complete

---

### UPDATE

Changed engine to MEMORY which reduced the time to a more reasonable 30 mins.

---

The purpose of the query is to identify the first document where one out of many potential needles are a match. Needles are searched in a pre-determined order (ex: "NEW YORK" is searched before YORK. Done this way because a strategy relying on queries like YORK -"NEW YORK" would be impractical).

Matches are identified by Sphinx, which requires, maybe, 30 minutes to generate a 10GB file. This file is then fed to mySQL to pick up the first matching needle in a given document.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE someTable`.  We need to see the Engine, datatypes, `PRIMARY KEY`, etc.  Also, how much RAM do you have and what is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: I have added some details to the question. The table being myIsam, the innoDB buffer pool size is irrelevant.

Comment: What was the setting of `key_buffer_size`?  How much RAM?  How big is the index on the table?  (These lead to discovering whether it was I/O-bound, and whether it could have been prevented with a simple config change.)

Comment: On initial run, key_buffer_size was the default value (which I haven't noted). Increased to 4G.

FWIW - test run starts with 477M+ and completes with 116M+ unique docIDs

Comment: Consider making the table InnoDB.